# Não retorna o ID no Javascript em duas Funções diferentes

Tags: javascript, php, html

Olá, pessoal. Tudo bem?

Tenho uma função em Javascript que quando eu clico em um botão `.produto-item` ele me retorna o id respectivo daquele produto que estou selecionando.

O problema é que eu preciso que quando eu clique no botão `.btnMais` ele me retorne esse mesmo ID pois vou estar adicionando mais produtos, ou seja aumentando a quantidade, e quando aciono a função `btnMais`, me retorna `undefined`.

[Retorno do ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMy6H.png)

Nessa imagem temos o exemplo de quando eu clico na `.produto-item` ele me retorna o ID e quando eu clico em `.btnMais` não retorna.

Ou seja preciso que quando eu chame a função `.btnMais` ela me retorne o mesmo ID de `.produto-item` retornou.

Tenho dois arquivos para isso sendo eles:

**JAVASCRIPT (funcaoAtualizaProduto.js):**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.btnMais', function () {
        var idProduto = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(idProduto);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.produto-item', function () {
        var idProduto = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(idProduto);

        var quantidadePedido = 1;

        $("#submit").click(function () {
      
            $.ajax({
                url: "processAtualizaProduto.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    idProduto: idProduto,
                    quantidadePedido: quantidadePedido 
                }
            });
        });
  
    });
    
});
```

E

**ARQUIVO PHP COM O HTML(incluirPedido.php):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="funcaoAtualizaProduto.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        // Lista para armazenar produtos selecionados com contadores
        var produtosSelecionados = [];

        // Função para lidar com o produto selecionado e atualizar o input
        function selecionarProduto(nomeProduto) {
            // Verifica se o produto já foi selecionado antes
            var produtoExistente = produtosSelecionados.find(function (produto) {
                return produto.nome === nomeProduto;
            });

            if (produtoExistente) {
                // Se o produto já existir, apenas incrementa o contador
                produtoExistente.contador++;
            } else {
                // Se for um novo produto, adiciona à lista com contador 1
                produtosSelecionados.push({ nome: nomeProduto, contador: 1 });
            }

            // Atualiza a lista de produtos selecionados na interface
            atualizarListaProdutosSelecionados();
        }
        // Função para aumentar a quantidade de um produto
        function aumentarQuantidade(nomeProduto) {
            var produtoSelecionado = produtosSelecionados.find(function (produto) {
                return produto.nome === nomeProduto;
            });

            if (produtoSelecionado) {
                produtoSelecionado.contador++;
                atualizarListaProdutosSelecionados();
            }

        }

        // Função para atualizar a lista de produtos selecionados na interface
        function atualizarListaProdutosSelecionados() {
            var listaProdutosSelecionados = document.getElementById('produtosSelecionados');
            listaProdutosSelecionados.innerHTML = '';

            produtosSelecionados.forEach(function (produto) {
                var itemLista = document.createElement('li');
                itemLista.textContent = produto.nome + ' (' + produto.contador + ')';

                // Adiciona botão "+" 
                var btnMais = document.createElement('button');
                btnMais.textContent = '+';
                btnMais.classList.add('btnMais'); // Adiciona classe btnMais ao botão
                btnMais.onclick = function () { aumentarQuantidade(produto.nome, produto.id); }; // Passa o nome e o ID do produto

                itemLista.appendChild(btnMais);

                listaProdutosSelecionados.appendChild(itemLista);
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
   
    <!-- Modal de seleção de produtos -->
    <div id="modalProduto">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <ul id="listaProdutos" class="lista-produtos">
                <?php
                $valorProduto = 40;
                $quantidadeProduto = 15;
                $nomeProduto = 'Arroz';
                $idProduto = 1;
                echo "<li class='produto-item' data-id='$idProduto' onclick=\"selecionarProduto('$idProduto - $nomeProduto')\">" . $idProduto . " - " . $nomeProduto . '<br>' . ' <span style="color: red;"> Valor: </span> ' . $valorProduto . '<br>' . '</td>' . '<td><span style="color: blue;"> Quantidade: </span> ' . $quantidadeProduto . "</li>";
                ?>
            </ul>
    
            <!-- Lista de produtos selecionados -->
            <ul id="produtosSelecionados" class="lista-produtos-selecionados"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Com esses dois trechos de código e utilizando o console é possível reproduzir o erro que estou tendo quando clico em `.btnMais` e é retornado o valor indefinido.

Comment: No último trecho de código você está criando o botão btnMais de forma dinâmica, mas não atribui o campo `data-id` nele, então sempre que fizer `$(this).data('id')` não existirá o valor.

Comment: Preciso pegar o mesmo id do botão .produto-item, quando eu clicar no botão .btnMais.

Comment: quando tento usar a mesma variavel ele me da a mensagem de undefined ou me informa o ID porém multiplicando o valor.

Comment: Veja como montar um [mcve] aqui demonstrando o problema.

Comment: Eu preciso que ele puxe o mesmo ID quando clicar em + porém o ID fica na variável .produto-item.

Comment: Ok, obrigado! Vou refazer a pergunta.